# restart Activity from other Activity

Tags: android

I have two Activity A and B. I want to restart B activity when goes to B activity from A activity, How can I do this?

```
Intent send_show = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivty(send_show);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "restart" you simply can do this :

```
Intent send_show = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
finish(); //here restart the B because you are on B class
startActivty(send_show);
```

Otherwise you can call [`recreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29)

### Edit

Since you want to "restart" the timer you could do something like this :

```
public void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
  //you should restart timer or just cancel and re active it in onCreate() 
}
```

Comment: but I want to restart B activity not A Activity

Comment: Then when you do the `Intent` to A Activity you do this

Comment: B activity doesn't return to A activity.My application like that A activity has a push notification listener when push comes to Activity A calls B Activity and B activity shows picture when other push comes, B activty comes again. I need to restart B activity each time because B activity works with Timer and I want to destroy Timer

Comment: then in onDestroy simply restart the timer

Answer (score 0):

You mean you only need to deal Timer?

```
public Timer rebuildTimer(Timer timer){
   try{
      if(timer!=null){
         timer.cancel();
         timer = new Timer();
      }
   }catch(Throwable e){

   }
   return timer;
}

private Timer mTimer;

private void onNewIntent(){
    mTimer = rebuildTimer(mTimer);
}

private void onCreate(Some params){
    mTimer = rebuildTimer(mTimer);
}
```